# Silverlight: Binding to a LayoutRoot value from within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have a `DataTemplate` for a `ListBox`, where I have several controls that bind to an item. I would also like to bind to a value on `LayoutRoot.DataContext`. I'm unsure of how to do this.

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.Foo}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return "the moon";
        }
    }

    private int startIndex = 1;

    private IList<string> _data = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    public IList<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work; only the `_data` items are displayed. The following binding errors appear in the Debug output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Foo' property not found on 'foo' 'System.String' (HashCode=1502598398). BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.Foo' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Border' (HashCode=78299055); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Foo' property not found on 'bar' 'System.String' (HashCode=696029481). BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.Foo' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Border' (HashCode=78298703); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Foo' property not found on 'baz' 'System.String' (HashCode=696029489). BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.Foo' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Border' (HashCode=78298694); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

Do I have a syntax error somewhere?

**Update** I'm aiming for something that looks like this:

- foo
- the moon
- bar
- the moon
- baz
- the moon

Instead, all I'm getting is:

- foo
- bar
- baz

(I'm using Silverlight for Windows Phone 7.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you just want to bind your list to the ListBox then you do not need this line

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.Foo}" />`

EDIT: (I just tried this and this works)

```
<ListBox Name="_ViewMapsListBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.NameName, ElementName=MainGrid}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Codebehind:

private string NameName {get;set;}
void Testing()
{
    NameName = "testing";
    MainGrid.DataContext = this;
}
```

### Maybe, try setting the `Foo` in your main method after initialize()..

EDIT 2: (Okay I just tried this)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.Foo}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return "the moon";
        }
    }

    private int startIndex = 1;

    private IList<string> _data = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    public IList<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting the output like:

foo
the moon
bar
the moon
baz
the moon

Comment: That is still not working. I'm getting the same binding errors as before.

Comment: @Roasrch: ok I just noticed `PhoneApplicationPage`, so that it might be the difference there of why it is not working.

Comment: Hmm.... I wonder why that would be. How can I make this work on a `PhoneApplicationPage`?

Comment: You can create an object, that has the property you want, plus add the collection as a property. Then set the parent data context to that object and the listbox itemsource to the collection property of that object.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to bind to a resource.

1. I moved the Foo and Items properties to a new class => `SomeClass`.
2. Added namespace => `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"` in UserControl.
3. I set up a resource in the UserControl => `<local:SomeClass x:key="context"/>`.
4. I bound the Layoutroot.DataContext in xaml => `DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource context}}"`, although you could do this in code behind, too.
5. Finally, I bound the textbox.text to the resource. `Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource context}, Path=Foo}"`.

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <local:SomeClass x:Key="context" />
   </UserControl.Resources>

   <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource context}}">

       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource context}, Path=Foo}" />
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>

   </StackPanel>
   ```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace BindingTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private IList<string> _data = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        public IList<string> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _data;
            }
        }

        public string Foo { get { return "the moon"; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can bind to an element outside of your DataTemplate. Instead you need to expand the items that you're binding your ListBox to.

Comment: -1: ofcourse you can bind an element outside your DataTemplate. You specify the property and the ElementName to do that.